# How to convert a nested MovieClip to a SpriteSheet

Tags: flash, adobe, sprite-sheet

I'm participating in a contest for developing a mobile app. It ends after approximately 9 hours from posting this.

I've just discovered that Adobe Flash has issues with converting nesting MovieClips to spritesheets. For example, there http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/light_1 an option "Generate Sprite Sheet" applies only to the first level of nested animations.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
1)Instal Adobe AIR Runtime
2)Install this: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2939